# How can I efficiently merge timelines (with deduplication as a bonus)

Tags: algorithm, merge, timeline

Let's say I have a classic posts timeline, something like twitter, so posts can be: original post, repost, it can be liked post, it can be trending post, popular post etc.

When I fetch a page of items for the user, how do I parallelise database queries?

Let's say I want to fetch the next ten items (paged) where:

- two items are most popular (by `popularity` value)
- two are most recent (by `createdTime` value)
- two are most liked or most reposted items
- four are from my friends/people I follow?

Another subproblem is deduping items, but let's focus on the first.

What I do now is run the four queries in parallel.
Then with the results, I clean out duplicates, and see how much I'm mi
ssing (per category).
Then I should do a "rerun" - fetch more, let's say one of the "recents
" and one retweet are duplicates, I need to fetch the recents and retw
eets again, just in lower numbers.
Finally let's say I only have 3 posts from friends, I also need to fil
l it up with other categories, so that's more queries.

My solution works, but you can see it can explode pretty quickly.

What flags can I set on the main, master timeline collection (using MongoDB here), what metadata from redis or elsewhere would help me out h
ere?

I'm primarily looking at reducing parallel number of queries.

I was thinking of just fetching 10 of each category, then it's just 4
parallel queries, but it seems an antipattern to fetch unneeded data. But so does my current solution.

Is there a better way?

How else can I improve performance and, say, maintainability here?

Comment: You can use Redis for caching (see here: http://www.sitepoint.com/caching-a-mongodb-database-with-redis/), or for publish-subscribe queues(Pub/Sub).
Read about Redis: https://www.datadoghq.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Understanding-the-Top-5-Redis-Performance-Metrics.pdf and http://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro                                                                                               For Parallelising MongoDB Aggregation (your main question): 
http://pauldone.blogspot.com/2014/04/mongoparallelaggsharded.html.

Comment: I know about redis thing for caching, but that's not very specific. I wondered if there's a pattern or an algorithm to merge stuff. The parallel queries I do already, I just wanna do less of them. In any case, thanks for the links.